# How to add Java EE perspective to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perspective

I could not find the Java EE perspective in Eclipse Galileo.
I want to develop a web application, but for this I need to change the Eclipse perspective. But, I could not find the Java EE perspective.

Can anybody tell me how to add this to Eclipse?

Comment: Did you download the JavaEE version, or just the standard version?

Comment: It is not JavaEE version. Is there any way to add JavaEE perspective further

Answer (score 94):

Relevant steps:

Go to "Help" -> "Install New Software...".

In the new dialog, in the "Work with:" pull-down list, select "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo".
            (Note: Replace Indigo and the download list with download locations for your eclipse version)

Select the following packages to install:

```
       "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development". 
       "Programming langauges -> Eclipse Java Development Tools"
```

After installation is complete, if you restart eclipse, you should see an option for java perspective in "window -> open perspective -> " or "window -> open perspective -> other"

If the above does not work, check the following as well: 
[Java EE perspective in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945253/java-ee-perspective-in-eclipse)

Comment: agreed! this was very helpful

Answer (score 22):

In the latest version of Eclipse (eclipse 2019-12), you need to manually download and install different perspectives as per your need.
For Java EE perspective, Go to Help -> Install New Software...
Then in the new pop up dialogue box, select --All Available Sites-- from Work with drop down list. Select "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" from the list and click next, then accept the license. Click Finish.
After installation you can see "Java EE" in "Windows->Perspective->Open Perspective->Other Perspective.

Good luck fellas...

Answer (score 8):

`window` -> `open perspective` -> `select Java EE view` [`Other` (if you dont see it in there)] -> choose `java EE`

(Assuming you have installed javaEE extension already or downloaded a version that already has it installed)

Comment: See the comment above, without the right version loaded, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to see J2EE perspective, you would have probably selected Java standard edition during eclipse installation. However we can get these by downloading certain tools from eclipse market place.

Eclipse-->help-->Eclipse marketplace--> search below tools and install
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` then you can go for the following steps otherwise firstly download and install`Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` from the given link
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Photon/R

After installing, you can open `Java EE perspective` by follow the following step-

`window` -> `open perspective` -> select `Java EE` view

That's it.