# Java EE perspective in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have Standard version of eclipse Galileo. Now I want to develop enterprise applications on it. Any idea how can I get Java EE perspective? How to install Java EE tools in the standard version?

Comment: Galileo is getting very old, and you should probably just get the enterprise edition of Indigo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard edition can be upgraded to J2EE edition by installing the different plug-ins like WTP and so on.
Did you try to look at the update site for Galileo?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I installed the latest Eclipse platform, Indigo, first using the Ubuntu Software Center, and when I didn't see the JavaEE perspective, I though I'd gotten the wrong one. I deleted that and installed the Java EE version downloadable from `eclipse.org` -- but still no Java EE perspective available. Then I read the advice above (and elsewhere) about installing the WTP plugins.

I decided to blow away the previous installation of Eclipse, because I prefer installing everything through the normal package management system. Then, after having installed Eclipse again, through the Ubuntu Software Center (and not seeing the Java EE perspective)... but I'll tell the rest of the story as a set of instructions:

1. Install Eclipse. In Ubuntu, you can do it at least in these two ways:

   - Go to the Ubuntu Software Center, search for eclipse, and install "Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE"; or
   - Give the command `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt eclipse-emf eclipse-emf-examples eclipse-emf-sdk eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp eclipse-rse eclipse-xsd eclipse-xsd-sdk` (those are what I have after doing all these steps; they might not all be necessary, but can't hurt)
2. Open Eclipse, and give a directory to use as a workspace.
3. Go to "Help" -> "Install New Software...".
4. In the new dialog, in the "Work with:" pull-down list, select "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigoIndigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo".
5. Click the checkbox to the left of "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development".
6. Click the "Next >" button. The installation will start.
7. The dialog will now list the items to be installed, and ask you to confirm the installation. Click the "Next >" button. The installation will complete.
8. Now, back in the main window, in "Window" -> "Perspective", I still could not see "Java EE" -- but it might have been under the "Other" selection; I didn't check, and that's where it can be found now that I've done everything described here.
9. Click on "File" -> "New" -> "Dynamic Web Project". The existence of this selection means that you've successfully installed the web development tools.
10. Configure the project. After you've pressed "Finish", Eclipse should ask you whether you want to open the Java EE perspective.

By the way, some of those Eclipse packages that I give for installing through apt-get might have been installed during the Eclipse software update phase, as I didn't install all of them by myself. The most important ones are `eclipse`, `eclipse-platform`, `eclipse-platform-data`, `eclipse-pde`, and `eclipse-rcp`. The descriptions of all of them are:

```
eclipse - Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE
eclipse-cdt - C/C++ Development Tools for Eclipse
eclipse-emf - Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF)
eclipse-emf-examples - Eclipse EMF/XSD examples
eclipse-emf-sdk - Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) - (Source/Documentation)
eclipse-jdt - Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT)
eclipse-pde - Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)
eclipse-platform - Eclipse platform without plug-ins to develop any language
eclipse-platform-data - Eclipse platform without plug-ins to develop any language (data)
eclipse-rcp - Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP)
eclipse-rse - Eclipse Remote System Explorer (RSE)
eclipse-xsd - XML Schema Definition (XSD) for Eclipse
eclipse-xsd-sdk -
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to download newest version of eclipse "for Java EE Developers". 
It also includes standard version.

Comment: Yes, I know that is the most obvious solution. But for some reason and for some period I'm not able to download and have to manage with standard version. So I'm asking is there any way?

Comment: The problem with the version for Java EE Developers is that it tends to be incompatible with some of the plugins.  Such as Eclipse-Groovy.  And if you're writing unit tests with Groovy & Spock, or writing Grails apps, that's a serious problem.