# servers tab not visible in eclipse v3.7.2

Tags: android, web-services, tomcat7, eclipse-wtp

Hi i have developed a app which accesses the mysql database for login verification but my problem is that to include tomcat 7 server.

In the path Windows>Show view>Other i am not able to see the servers tab.

I am also not able to update the web tools platform.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Windows ->Customize Perspective ->Command Group Visibility -> check Server if it is unchecked.

make sure you have added tomcat to eclipse if  you don not have then add it.below steps will help you.

```
Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments 
Add
Apache > Apache Tomcat 5.5
```

You are done.Hope it will help.

Also make sure you downloaded the "**Eclipse For Java EE Developers**" package as I do not believe that the "**Eclipse for Java Developers**" contains the Servers view.

Here is the link:-

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1

Comment: server is not visible there alse

Comment: its not there and i dunno whats wrong...and i also disalbed my antivirus as it was not allowing me to update and when i try to update wtp it says it is already updated to the latest version...

Comment: check my edited answer and make sure you added tomcat to server runtime.

Comment: tomcat to server runtime?? How to do that i have installed wamp and put it online...even then it is not visible in eclipse...

Comment: "server runtime" server->runtime environments that i meant.try adding your tomcat as i told how in my answer.

Comment: that is what i telling you that click on Add and you will able to add the server from the directory you have installed it in.

Comment: i cant find this path Server > Runtime Environments in preferences.

Comment: This solution fixed the problem, but then tomcat wasn't showing, so i used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments

Answer (score 6):

It might be possible that the JAVAEE perspective is not installed or the perspective is not shifted to JAVAEE.

Try 
windows > perspective > open perspective > other >JAVAEE

If you can't see JAVAEE in the others tab, then it is not installed.
In the latest version of eclipse (2019-12), it needs to be manually installed.
 Please follow the below link to install it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405942/2606228

Answer (score 2):

I am using Luna. I have following following steps.

1. Help -> Install New Software
2. Choose "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" site
3. Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
4. Select i) Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.6.3.v201501281502
   ii) Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.6.3.v201502041526
   iii) Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.6.3.v201501312139
5. Restart Eclipse.