# Appach Tomcat is shutting down automatically when i run it

Tags: tomcat, jvm

In the last weeks Appach was working normally but today when i want to start appach-tomcat, it shuts down automatically, this is the log message in catalina :

```
29-Jun-2018 11:06:49.714 INFO [main] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 32769 ms
29-Jun-2018 11:06:49.745 SEVERE [main] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: 
create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:420)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:713)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:659)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: check for zombie process or anything listening to the Tomcat ports defined in server.xml, setenv,.. (for example with `netstat -tulpna`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot start Tomcat 7 server - java.net.BindException: Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271828/cannot-start-tomcat-7-server-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the port 8005 is used by another application, so i changed to 8006 and it works fine.